# When I import cling from dj_static is error

Tags: django, heroku

I want to deploy the django project in Heroku, but the application is constantly crashes.
I realized that the case in line **from dj_static import Cling**

I installed dj_static.

```
(venv)alex@PC:~/projects/hellodjango$ pip freeze
Django==1.6.4
dj-static==0.0.5
...
```

But the following error occurs:

```
>>> from dj_static import Cling
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/dj_static.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.handlers import StaticFilesHandler as DebugHandler
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/handlers.py", line 8, in <module>
    from django.contrib.staticfiles.views import serve
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/staticfiles/views.py", line 13, in <module>
    from django.views import static
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/static.py", line 96, in <module>
    template_translatable = ugettext_noop("Index of %(directory)s")
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 65, in gettext_noop
    return _trans.gettext_noop(message)
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 52, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 54, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/alex/projects/hellodjango/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 47, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
```

How to solve this problem?

Comment: Make sure the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE is set. For example, did you start the example above with `python manage.shell` or just `python`? You'll need to do the former

Comment: No, does not work in shell, only in python.
I installed:
`heroku config:set DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=conf.settings`.
conf - my app with settings.py.
I installed correctly configure?